# Remove rows from a dataframe that match two columns in another dataframe R

Tags: r, match

I am struggling to remove rows from a data frame in R, where values from different columns match two values from different columns in a second data frame.

For example, given the following pseudo-data:

```
ID1 <- c(5,10,6)
ID2 <- c(3,5,4)
Value <- rnorm(3)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID1, ID2, Value)

x <- c()
y <- c()
z <- c()

for (i in 1:10){
a <- rep(i, 10)
b <- c(1:10)
c <- rnorm(10)
x <- c(x, a)
y <- c(y, b)
z <- c(z, c)
}

DF2 <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

I would like to remove the rows from `DF2` where the combination of `x` and `y` matches `ID1` and `ID2` from `DF1` (ie `x = 5 and y = 3`, `x = 10 and y = 5`, `x = 6 and y = 4`, but also `x = 3 and y = 5`, `x = 5 and y = 10`, `x = 4 and y = 6`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make exclude list

```
excl <- data.frame(
  x = c(DF1$ID1, DF1$ID2),
  y = c(DF1$ID2, DF1$ID1))
```

Then use anti join:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(DF2, excl, by = c("x", "y"))
```

Or using paste as suggested in the comments:

```
DF2[! paste(DF2$x, DF2$y) %in% 
      c(paste(DF1$ID1, DF1$ID2),
        paste(DF1$ID2, DF1$ID1)), ]
```

Comment: or use `%in%` after `paste`ing

Answer (score 0):

Another option by using @zx8754's `excl` and `match_df` function of `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
DF2[-as.numeric(rownames(match_df(DF2,excl))),]
```